# Cakephp paging two models in one action

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a comment system based on the page path of the website. In other words, every page should be commentable and list comments. I have paginated list for the posts, in-which every page contains 5 posts, it may be accessed something like the following:

```
http://mywebsite.com/posts
http://mywebsite.com/posts/page:2
http://mywebsite.com/posts/page:3
etc
```

Now, let says that I have comments should be paged on `http://mywebsite.com/posts/page:2` with 10 comments per the page, this should mean that `posts/page:2` should has the first 10 comments and I need something like `/posts/page:2/comments/commentsPage:2` to render the next 10 comments in the `/posts/page:2`.

How could I achive something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This ist not possible:

```
/posts/page:2/comments/commentsPage:2
```

You should use your Posts Model for the posts (as I believe you do) and a Comment Model for the comments.

Then you can link your Posts and Comments.

Check out: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html